# Correlating aggregates by Saga ID instead of an additional aggregate root

Tags: c#, mysql, cqrs, event-sourcing, saga

That's my first question ever, so excuse me if it's unclear or incomplete, and let me know how I can provide more info.

I'm trying to build an email ticketing system using CQRS + ES. So emails are joined into conversations (sort of a la outlook conversations, but with different criteria for joining) and these conversations are then assigned a ticket where people can interact with (tag it, update its status, add notes...).

Currently, once an mail is received, a new Mail aggregate is created which raises a `MailReceived` event.
`ProcessManager` router (or saga router) tries to find a matching "ConversationSaga" based on the criteria or creates a new one. The saga sends a command to assign the conversation Id to the Mail aggregate --> which raises a `ConversationAssigned` mail.

The last event, `ConversationAssigned`, is intercepted by the Ticketing bounded context that generates a ticket or update an existing one based on the conversation Id. once ticket is created/updated, the event is routed to the ConversationSaga to send needed commands (ApplyTicketToMail --> MoveMailToFolder --> ...)

**My questions are:**
1- is it abnormal to use Saga Id as the conversation Id linking several mails together?
2- I was checking the possibility of creating a `Conversation Aggregate` root, but i'm still new to event sourcing and don't know how to handle event sourced entities within AggregateRoots (i need Mail to be an event sourced aggregate).

***PS:*** i'm using C#, with MsSql DB and nhibernate and messaging is over RabbitMq.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems to read/understand your descriptions, but the overall design seems fine to me.  In particular, it is common practice to orchestrate multiple ARs from a single saga.

From what  you wrote, I would indeed suggest to create a new `Conversation` aggregate that is decoupled from the `Mail` AR, in particular since you already named it like that ("conversation"), and thus it appears to be a term from the ubiquitous language.

Comment: Sorry for the messy description, but thanks for the reply. Just one thing i didnt get which seems to be my issue with creating a conversation AR: what do you mean by decoupled?

Comment: I just meant to make `Conversation` and `Mail` individual ARs.